# SAML 2.0 with C#

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

I have done so many googling on SAML 2.0 usage with C#, but not found any understandable link. So hope someone can help on this

1) How the SSO is working - A diagram on calls

2) I'm using ping federated. So what will be the working flow of that? Got 0% idea with their documentation

3) Do I need to write any code to embed SSO with ping federated? If so is that regarding IDP or is it for SP?

4) How to handle SAML 2.0 requests through C#.net. What are the technologies (ex: send request : plain http redirect , receive response : http handler or a wcf service)

Comment: 1)  Ask **one** question per question, not four.  2) What did you not understand from your many links?

Answer (score 3):

Use a SAML client side stack like Kentor. That has good documentation.

Your client will be the SP. Ping will be the IDP.

No, no code just Ping configuration.